# How to attack CBC and OFB by knowning plaint-text and its cipher-text?

Tags: encryption, cryptography

In the CBC and OFB encryption with fixe IV and by knowing the plaint-text and its cipher-text how we can decrypt the other plaint-texts?

Thank you

Comment: Off topic here, but for CBC cannot. The other plaintext is still protected by the key, and the key in turn is protected by the block cipher. The fixed IV just let you spot identical blocks in CBC. For OFB you would get the same block from the block cipher, which in turn lets you retrieve a XOR of the plaintext block with another plaintext block. And if you know one, then you'd know the other.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not about programming, and as this is an assignment, it is not on topic on https://crypto.stackexchange.com either.

Comment: Thank you @MaartenBodewes for your answer.